# PageView make changes in changed page flutter

Tags: flutter, pageviews

I have a PageView.builder and want to rebuild my page when I swipe left or right. how can I make it?

```
PageView.builder(
            controller: _controller,
            itemCount: items.length,
            allowImplicitScrolling: true,
            reverse: false,
            onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) => MyCustomPage(
                  item: _item,
                  onUpdate: ( controller) =>
                      _onUpdate(controller),
                )),
```

```
void _onPageChanged(int position) {
    _item = _items[position];
    _style = ItemStyle.none;
    _callSetStateIfNeeded();
  }
```

Comment: post your _onPageChanged method

Comment: calling `setState` inside `onPageChanged` callback rebuilds the parent stateful widget, what kind of problems do you have with `setState`?

Comment: in ``MyCustomPage`` I have ``_onTap`` bool variable, at first is false, when I tap in item I change it to true, and when I change page and returned in this page, I want that ``_onTap`` be false, but now is true